# Particle moving along an ellipse; negative/positive displacement

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem.

A particle moves along an ellipse  $$3x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ with a position vector $$\vec{r} (t)= (f(t), g(t))$$ the displacement is such that the horizontal component of the velocity vector in each  instant $ t $ is  $ -g(t)$.

Is the particle having a negative or positive displacement?

Show that the vertical component of the velocity vector in instant  $ t $ is proportional to $ f(t)$. Find the constant of proportionality.

This is what I have:

$$\vec{r} (t)= ( \cos(t)/\sqrt{3} , \sin(t))$$

$$\vec{v} (t) = ( -\sin(t)/\sqrt{3} , \cos(t))$$

Velocity vector with horizontal component  $ -g(t)$:

$$\vec{v} (t) = ( -\sin(-sin(t))/\sqrt{3} , \cos(t))$$
This is equal to:
$$\vec{v} (t) = ( \sin(sin(t))/\sqrt{3} , \cos(t))$$

My conclusion, if I am not wrong, is that since both components of the velocity vector are positive then the particle displacement is positive.

I am still not sure about what to do regarding if the vertical component of the velocity vector in instant  $ t $ is proportional to $ f(t)$, and about finding the constant of proportionality.

Any tips on how to solve that problem?

Edit:

Constant of proportionality

[image: Constant of proportionality]

Please excuse my english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particle moves along $3x^2+y^2=1$

So we define $\vec r(t) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt3} \cos (at), \sin (at))$ where $a$ is a constant. For $a = 1$, it will take $2\pi$ unit of time for the particle to go along the ellipse and return to its starting position.

$\vec v(t) = (- \frac{a}{\sqrt3} \sin (at), a \cos (at))$

We also know that $\vec r(t) = (f(t), g(t))$ such that $x$ component of velocity vector at any given $t$ is $-g(t)$.

So what is the value of $a$? Can you take it from here?

Comment: a is the square root of 3, so the particle moves counter clockwise right? I realize now I made a huge mistake, but could you please explain why "a" is needded? I also added a picture to the post with the constant of proportionality, could you please look at it and tell me if it is correct?

Comment: yes ratio of proportionality is correct. yes it will be counterclockwise. if you do not have $a$ or $a = 1$, what does that mean? you are assuming that it is taking $2\pi$ unit of time to complete one round but that may or may not be right.

Comment: As per given condition, it is taking only $2 \pi / \sqrt3$ unit of time to complete one rotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help with this question and the one about the hyperbola

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You claim that
$$ \vec r(t) = (f(t), g(t))
   \stackrel?= \left( \tfrac1{\sqrt3} \cos(t), \sin(t)\right). \tag1$$

Therefore you claim that at $t = 0,$ the particle is at
$\left( \tfrac1{\sqrt3}, 0\right)$.
You claim that at time $t = \frac\pi2,$ the particle is at $(0, 1).$
You claim that the particle continues around the ellipse counterclockwise and that if we note the position of the particle at any instant, it takes exactly $2\pi$ units of time for the particle to return to that position.

Very specifically, you claim that $f(t) \stackrel?= \tfrac1{\sqrt3} \cos(t)$
and that $g(t) \stackrel?= \sin(t).$
This is exactly what Equation $(1)$ says.

*None* of this can be deduced from the statement that
a particle moves along the ellipse  $3x^2 + y^2 = 1$ with a position vector
$\vec{r} (t)= (f(t), g(t))$.
You cannot even deduce it from the statement that the displacement is such that the horizontal component of the velocity vector in each  instant $ t $ is  $ -g(t)$,
because in fact that statement implies that Equation $(1)$ is *not* the correct equation of motion of the particle.

If Equation $(1)$ were correct, then the horizontal component of the velocity of the particle at any time $t$ would be
$-\tfrac1{\sqrt3} \sin(t).$
But since you have claimed that $g(t) \stackrel?= \sin(t),$ it follows that
$-g(t) \stackrel?= -\sin(t) \neq -\tfrac1{\sqrt3} \sin(t).$
So the horizontal component of the velocity would not be $-g(t).$

I have no idea why you would think the horizontal component of $\vec v(t)$
is $-{\sin(-\sin(t))}/{\sqrt3}.$
According to your other claims, that's $f'(-g(t)),$ not $-g(t).$

What you do know is that the position of the particle at any instant can be described by the formula
$$ \left( \tfrac1{\sqrt3} \cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)\right) $$
for some number $\theta$. If you knew the position of the particle at time $t$ you could find a value of $\theta$ that makes the formula above produce the coordinates of that position, and then you could declare that this defines $\theta$ as a function of $t$. That is, you could conclude that
$$ \vec r(t) = \left( \tfrac1{\sqrt3} \cos(\theta(t)), \sin(\theta(t))\right). $$

You could even reasonably conclude that this should be true for some continuous function, that is, you can suppose that $\theta(t)$ is a continuous function of $t$.
(You could just as easily make it discontinuous by randomly adding multiples of $2\pi$ to some values of $\theta(t)$, but you can choose not to do such a silly thing.)

You could even reasonably assume $\theta(t)$ is differentiable.
There's actually nothing in the problem statement that requires $\theta(t)$
to be differentiable everywhere, but it's a reasonable assumption and it does need to be true in enough places to answer the question.

Assuming that $\theta(t)$ is differentiable, you should be able to apply the chain rule to find components of the particle's velocity,
and setting the horizontal component equal to $-g(t)$ you may then be able to draw some conclusions about $\theta(t)$ which will tell you in which direction the particle travels around the ellipse.

Comment: Thank you David for your explanation, it made me realize how wrong I was.